# What's the difference when setting the type like these?

Tags: typescript

`const example : type = () => {}`

`const example = () : type => {}`

Are they different?

if they are different, how can i set type `() => {}` ?

`() : type  => {}` Is it correct?

Comment: You need to explain this question further. Also, I advise you don't say "like these" in the title as people do not know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
const example : type = () => {}
```

This declares a variable `example` of type `type`. Since we're assigning a function to it, the type `type` had better be a function type (like `() => void`), or something compatible with a function type (like `any` or `unknown`).

```
const example = () : type => {}
```

This declares a variable called `example` (whose type is inferred). The value of that variable is a function which *returns* a value of type `type`. Since the function body clearly doesn't return anything, `type` had better be `void` (or `undefined` if `noImplicitReturns` is off).

In the first case, `type` is the type of the entire function. In the second, it's the type of the return value *from* the function.

Answer (score 0):

Both syntaxes that you provided are valid ways to declare a function type in TypeScript.

the first one:

```
const example : type = () => {}
```

This syntax declares a constant variable example of type type, which is a function type that takes no parameters and returns a value.

and second one:

```
 const example = () : type => {}
```

This syntax declares a constant variable example and defines its type using a function type annotation. It specifies that example is a function that takes no parameters and returns a value of type type.

if you used further with parameters the do this:

```
let example: (x: type, y: type) => type;
```

if your function is returns void without parameters do this:

```
let example : Function;
```